# PhP Artisan command to create class from database Laravel 5?

Tags: php, database, class, laravel-5, php-5.6

Does a php artisan command exists to create all the necessary class from a database ?

I have a database filled with several table (run with MySQL), and I would like to have a php class abstraction, which means every trivials procedure (create, update, delete, insert) are automatically created through this process for each classes representing a table in my database.

The point is to be able to call every class with same function for the CRUD :

```
User->create(); // may return the last id inserted

Book->update("create_date", "2015-09-09");

User->delete(1);   // may remove the user with primary key "1"
Book->delete(410); // may remove the book with primary key "410"
```

Or is there an existing external Laravel 5 compatible plugin to perform this task ?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the [make:model](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#defining-models) command.

For example:

```
php artisan make:model User
```

will make a model for your User table (the naming conventions can all be overridden).

You will need to run the `make:model Name` command for each table individually, Artisan can't do each one for you automatically, but once created you'll have all of the standard [Eloquent methods](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent) available which will allow you to `create, update, delete, show`.

Comment: The command worked like a charm, nevertheless I have an empty class : `class Book extends Model { }`. Knowing I already configured my database connection in `config/database.php`. Is that normal ?

Comment: Yes, completely normal. Your ```Book``` class extends ```Model``` which allows it to inherit the Eloquent methods used for database querying. Check the documentation in my answer to learn more about Eloquent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use artisan command :
 install Laracademy Generators:

```
composer require "laracademy/generators"
```

Then add Laracademy Generators into your config/app.php file:

```
Laracademy\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider::class
```

Alternatively, you can add the provider to your ‘app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php’ if you only want to use this provider for local development:

```
public function register(){
if($this->app->environment() == 'local') {
    $this->app->register('\Laracademy\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider');
}}
```

Now you have everything you need to start using the Laracademy Generators. Let’s explore how to use it and what are the available options.If you check your Artisan cli, a new command will appear in the list:

```
generate:modelfromtable
```

First, you can pass –all flag to tell Laracademy Generators to generate models for all tables existed in your database:

```
php artisan generate:modelfromtable --all
```

Hope this helped you :)